# Русский язык и культура речи

Tags: грамотная-речь

1.О случившемся Генкин ничего не знал вследствие недоведения до него обстоятельств дела со стороны Щеголевой.
2.Находясь наедине с Дудиной, Головач представилась возможность обо всем договориться с ней.
3.Потом Уткин выбежал во двор, где его задержали, спрятавшись за дерево.
4.Нарушив правила дорожного движения, пострадало три человека.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Первую фразу легче сказать просто правильно, без канцеляризма:  ...потому что Щёголева не ознакомила (не рассказала) ...
   И всё ж возьму на себя труд хоть как-то подлечить несчастное предложение. В приведённом варианте двусмысленность: то ли Щёголева чего-то там не довела до Генкина, то ли с её стороны были "обстоятельства дела".
   Два следующих  примера - из серии "Подъезжая к сией станции.., с меня слетела шляпа".
   А именно: неправильное построение предложений с деепричастными оборотами.
    2-ое можно поправить очень легко: имела (получила)возможность. Попутно замечу, что обычно возможность предОставляется.
2. Тут вообще неясно даже, кто всё-таки прятался: а)если Уткин, то ...когда он спрятался за... б) если те, кто его - того - следовало бы вместо деепричастия взять причастие: ...спрятавшиеся за деревом.
3. ПострадалИ три человека (мн.число). Если уже знакомый нам оборот не трогать, получается, что ПДД нарушили все трое. Вот и поплатились. Может, впредь воспитаннее будут.